# Generics: type in front of other type?

Tags: java

What is the purpose of the following generic code?

```
class A {
   static <T> int f(T a) {
      int i = 0;
      return i;
   }
}
```

Why is there an additional `<T>` in front?  Is it erroneous?

Comment: Not erroneous.  It's a generic method.  It means that `T` can be any type.  I'm certain this question is a duplicate, so I'm looking for the best duplicate right now.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem how can a function return two types?

Comment: `<T>` is a type parameter. It is declaring, in the scope of the method, a type variable named `T` with the (implicit) upper bound of `java.lang.Object`.  The type parameter makes the method generic. and is why the type of the method parameter `a` can be `T`. The return type is `int` (and only `int`).

Comment: it is a Generic syntax

Comment: It doesn't return two types.  It returns an `int`.  The `<T>` declares that the letter `T` will be used as a type parameter.  In this case, it means that `T` can be any reference type at all.

Comment: Refer to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html